# Call function in shell script

Tags: bash, function, shell

I have the following code, that I want to be inside an function `getsum()`. I tried with the following code working without the function. When I run `./sum 5 6` I get `11`.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for i in $@; do sum=$((sum+i)); done
echo $sum
exit 0
```

But how can I put it in a function doing the same job?

I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
sums() {
    sum=0
    for i in $@; do sum=$((sum+i)); done
    echo $sum
    exit 0
}

sums
```

Comment: Apart from `exit 0` your function looks fine.
That statement will terminate your shell!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass the arguments (`$@`) to the function `sum()` that you pass to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sums() {
    sum=0
    for i in $@; do sum=$((sum+i)); done
    echo $sum
    exit 0
}

sums "$@" # Note this line
```